# Speaker makes rough sound when connected to wifi!

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, wi-fi

I have a tablet with android version 4.0.4. When the tablet is **connected** to wifi network the speaker makes some "non-electrical" (irregular krrrrrrrr) sound. I don't exactly know when did this problem started.  I bought it just a couple months back. Is ti some software problem or hardware problem? How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion this should be due to the interference of WiFi signal. Normally, these radio wave generators and sensitive components like speaker should be shielded. This shield might have been damaged or lost its efficiency.  This could happen when you drop the tablet or due to manufacturing fault. Either way, I would take it to the service centre for a fix or replacement.

Comment: What tablet? It sounds like a hardware problem. I would check the warranty on your device and get it returned/repaired.